problem when accessing api with axios when backend is running?

api.js:14 GET http://localhost:8080/api/todos/todos net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest@xhr.js:180xhr@xhr.js:24dispatchRequest@dispatchRequest.js:53_request@Axios.js:159request@Axios.js:50Axios.<computed>@Axios.js:181wrap@bind.js:9getTodos@api.js:14fetchTodos@index.js??clonedRule…e=script&lang=js:27created@index.js??clonedRule…e=script&lang=js:23callWithErrorHandling@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:349callWithAsyncErrorHandling@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:356callHook@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3414applyOptions@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3339finishComponentSetup@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6850setupStatefulComponent@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6777setupComponent@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6716mountComponent@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5265processComponent@runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5243
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api/todos', 
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }
});

export default {
    getTodos() {
        return apiClient.get('/todos');
    },
    createTodo(todo) {
        return apiClient.post('/todos', todo);
    },
    updateTodo(id, todo) {
        return apiClient.put(`/todos/${id}`, todo);
    },
    deleteTodo(id) {
        return apiClient.delete(`/todos/${id}`);
    }
};


From what I see, you are trying to access http://localhost:8080/api/todos/todos. Replacing the  baseURL with 'http://localhost:8080/api' might help.
Also, I suggest improving the formatting of your questions in the future. Please try to include a clear description of when the issue occurs and specify what you want to achieve.

That's definitely a problem as the path seems to get duplicated from OPs code.
If that doesn't work, error 500 sounds like OP should be searching the problem on the backend.

Thank you so much it solve my problem. appreciate it.
